# Find All Uses of a Specific Reference

Tags: c#

I currently have a website, whose code behind references some functions within another project within the same solution. I have been tasked with pulling out this website and its existing functionality and putting it into its own solution.

Currently the code behind looks similar to this:

```
using BusinessObjectsProject;

namespace BatchProject.Web
{
    public partial class AutoShoppingCart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static BatchProject LoadProjectDetails(string projectId)
        {
            return BusinessObjectsProject.BatchBo.ReadBatchProject(ConvertHelper.SafeConvertInt32(projectId));
        }
    }
}
```

However there are many (more than 20) functions that make use of the BusinessObjectsProject reference.

Is there a simple way to list the BusinessObjectsProject functions in the AutoShoppingCart class? I want to ensure that I copy over everything to ensure existing functionality.

Comment: Visual Studio? Right click, `Find all references`..!

Comment: You could also just pull it out and see what breaks.

Comment: what do you mean by *I have been tasked with pulling out this website and its existing functionality and putting it into its own solution*? Solution doesn't even matter actually. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Derp, find all references and then just check the which ones are in the file I'm removing.

Comment: @Chris Post as an answer and I'll gladly accept it

Comment: @Blorgbeard yeah I could ... was attempting to see if there a "nicer" way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, simply right click `BusinessObjectsProject` and select `Find All References` (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>).

The solution suggested by Blorgbeard is also useful, just remove/rename the class and see what breaks.